# Keras - Deal with inputs of 2 different shapes

Tags: machine-learning, keras

I'm trying to make a model that deals with categorical data of the shape (891,4,20) and numerical data of the shape (891,4).
To explain further, the categorical data has 891 sequences, 4 different types of categorical, and each is one-hot encoded to be a length of 20.
The numerical data has 891 sequences and have 4 different types.
Here's my attempt so far:

```
def get_model():
    # Model 
    categorical_input = Input(shape=(891,4,20), dtype='float32', name='categorical_input')
    numberic_input = Input(shape=(891,4), dtype='float32', name='numberic_input')

    normalisation = BatchNormalization()(numberic_input)

    dense1 = Dense(16,activation='relu')(categorical_input)
    dense2 = Dense(16,activation='relu')(normalisation)

    concatenated = concatenate([dense1, dense2])

    result = Dense(1,activation='sigmoid')(concatenated)

    model_fnc = Model([categorical_input, numberic_input], result)
    model_fnc.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy', optimizer='rmsprop', metrics=['acc'])

    return model_fnc
```

But it seems like Keras won't allow that because of the input shape of categorical and numeric inputs are different. Here's the error message:

```
ValueError: A `Concatenate` layer requires inputs with matching shapes except for the concat axis. Got inputs shapes: [(None, 891, 4, 16), (None, 891, 16)]
```

I thought that after going through dense1 and dense2 layers, the output of each of those layers should be of the shape (16,), which should be matching for concatenate. Can someone suggest a solution and explain why I am wrong? Thanks!

Comment: why can‘t you do a (891,80) matrix and simply join the numeric matrix, so that you have a (891,84) matrix?

Comment: @Peter I guess I can...

Comment: and why don‘t you do that and feed this into the model? Should be okay data representation wise